# Java Statements, processing precedence ("dangling else")

Tags: java, if-statement

Given the following valid piece of code:

```
Boolean a = false;

if (a)
   System.out.println("A");
else
   System.out.println("!A");
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html), `if` including its condition and inner `statement` is also a `statement`. For example:

```
   if (b){
      System.out.println("B");
   }
```

is a `statement`.

However, when we are going to replace an existing statement with another one, it shouldn't touch the overall logic, right? Assuming we replace the (Expression)-`statement` with the `if-statement` above :

```
Boolean a = false;
Boolean b = false:

if (a)
   if (b){
      System.out.println("A and B");
   }
else
   System.out.println("!A");
```

Java Compiler will interpret the code example as follows (full braces for explanation):

```
Boolean a = false;
Boolean b = false:

if (a){
   if (b){
      System.out.println("A and B");
   } else {
      System.out.println("!A");
   }
}
```

which is not the initial logic.

So why is exchanging *one* statement against another changing the logic?

From the example one can clearly say, that the problem is just about the **braces**, but I cannot find information about the way java is exactly dealing with this, if braces are omitted.

Is there anything written down about this behavior? Why does java prefer to connect the `else` to the more recent `if`, rather than the first `if` it encounters while parsing?

Comment: If it connect's the else to the first `if`, what will happen if there's another else below it?

Comment: The statement you quoted from ORACLE probably applies only when braces are used.

Comment: This is a common area of ambiguity. [Wikipedia Dangling else article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) You said "which is not the initial Logic." in your question, but the thing is is that according to the Java compiler it *was* the initial logic. If Java was like Python in that it cared about indentation it would have been able to distinguish as you expected it to because the `else` was on the same level as the first `if`, but enforcing indentation is effectively the same as enforcing the use of curly braces.

Comment: If you are truely interested in knowing all there is to know about Java the [Java Specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) is a valuable tool. Section 2 would be of interest to you and your question.

Comment: @Marco13 you should post relevant this text and the link as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course, the answer is in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html). The relevant section is [section 14.5, "Statements"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5), which describes exactly this case:

> As in C and C++, the if statement of the Java programming language suffers from the so-called "dangling `else` problem," illustrated by this misleadingly formatted example:
>
> ```
> if (door.isOpen())
>     if (resident.isVisible())
>         resident.greet("Hello!");
> else door.bell.ring();  // A "dangling else"
> ```
>
> The problem is that both the outer `if` statement and the inner `if` statement might conceivably own the `else` clause. In this example, one might surmise that the programmer intended the `else` clause to belong to the outer `if` statement.

And finally:

> **The Java programming language, like C and C++ and many programming languages before them, *arbitrarily decrees* that an `else` clause belongs to the innermost `if` to which it might possibly belong**.

<sub>(emphasis by me)</sub>

Comment: Thx for your answer. I think this is pretty obvious when looking at the full example, but taking the *replace statement with statement* idea is just not what the compiler does - because it ofc. does not care about the *prior* allocation of the `else`. (Well, that's why I always use full braces, just encountered this due to lazyness on some quick code)

Answer (score 1):

By having it associate with the most recent `if` you know you only need to read the most recent `if` to understand the logic.  Otherwise you would have read all the `if` and all the `else` clauses to understand any of them.

Say you didn't do most recent if, but least recent `if`.

```
if (a) 
  if (b) 
     something();
  else // if this is else to if (a)
     something();
else if (c) // what is this the else to?
  something();
else
  something();
```

When you have multiple else clauses, it is much easier to read if the else is for the most recent `if`

Comment: That's true (and documented in the JLS, see the answer from @Marco13)

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected, you indentation doesn't mean anything. `else` refers to the nearest if so it pertains to `if(b)`
You should have indended the code:

```
Boolean a = false;
Boolean b = false:

if (a)
   if (b){
      System.out.println("A and B");
   } else
      System.out.println("!A");
```

But in general it is always good practice to use braces `{}`

Comment: the question was about documentation

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behavior.**If after an if-statement,there is no curly braces,then only the first statement is treated as part of the true condition**.The problem with your example is that there is no braces to define the scope of statements and there is a curly brace right after the condition evaluating b.

After the first if-statement,the second if-statement uses a curly braces and  establishes precedence of statements.You should use the code like this:-

```
Boolean a = false;
Boolean b = false:

    if (a){
       if (b)
          System.out.println("A and B");
    }
    else
       System.out.println("!A");
```

Answer (score 0):

The DOM of a java program, called **AST**, abstract syntax tree, is a more pure structure, and in general used as basis to also talk about the meaning, semantics, of code.

The linear text has many parsing short-comings, like:

```
-(-y) equal to y for most int values
--y
```

The dangling `else` is one point.

In computer science only declarative languages (functions, logical) sometimes are treated on the symbolic level. C/C++ on the other hand is notoriously contextual.

Answer (score -4):

Java is an Object oriented language which essentially means that it follows bottom up approach while compiling the code.
That's why it considers the latest if statement as the companion to else part.