# No curly braces if else statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
int x = 5, y = 5, z = 5;
  if ( x != 5 )
    if ( y <= 7 )
    z = z + 4;
  else
    z = z + 2;
 System.out.println( z );
```

Will the "else" runs? Which "if" does it belong to? Why or why not? Thanks

Comment: You can run it to find out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Statements, processing precedence ("dangling else")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076762/java-statements-processing-precedence-dangling-else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will print out `5`. It doesn't even approach to the second `if-else`, because doesn't pass the first condition `x!=5` and the `else` statement is missing and it goes to the last line where you print the variable out. It's the same as:

```
int x=5, y=5, z=5;
if (x!=5) {
    if (y<=7) {
        z=z+4;
    } else {
        z=z+2;
    }
}
System.out.println(z);
```

That's the reason why using both of brackets `()` and `{}` correctly are more than recommended!

Answer (score 2):

`Else` usually goes with the last `if`, if  `{}` are not mentioned. So in your case `else` goes with `if ( y <= 7 )` and hence wont be executed.
Looking at your code it looks like you need it this way

```
int x = 5, y = 5, z = 5;
if ( x != 5 ){
    if ( y <= 7 )
    z = z + 4;
}
else{
    z = z + 2;
}
System.out.println( z );
```

So if you dont put brackets here that else wont execute.